# What does `%{%v:lua.…%}` mean in an option?

Tags: neovim

Currently trying to understand my neovim setup better.

So, looked into what a few classical options are set to.

```
:set statusline
```

yields

```
  statusline=%{%v:lua.require'heirline'.eval_statusline()%}
```

`:help %`<kbd>tab</kbd> was not very helpful.

So, could someone help me pick this apart? I found out `%{%…%}` is a lambda expression which gets re-evaluated as statusline expression.

`v:` would suggest we're entering `v`isual mode, but that makes no sense in the context.

So, I feel completely noobish, here.

Comment: Try `:help v:lua`

Comment: wait. We have a vim *variable* that's actually not a variable at all, but evaluated lua code? Uff. That sounds like a design decision!

Comment: I _think_ it's basically exposing the global Lua namespace as Vim Dict, which is similar to a Lua table (but without prototypes, if I understand Lua correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v:lua` is used to call Lua functions from Vimscript.

Quoting the `v:lua-call` help subject (*lua.txt*) from Neovim v0.10.0:

> From Vimscript the special `v:lua` prefix can be used to call Lua functions which are global or accessible from global tables.
>
> The expression
>
> ```
> call v:lua.func(arg1, arg2)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the Lua chunk
>
> ```lua
> return func(...)
> ```
>
> where the args are converted to Lua values.
>
> The expression
>
> ```
> call v:lua.somemod.func(args)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the Lua chunk
>
> ```lua
> return somemod.func(...)
> ```